# jquery hide all but first image in masonry

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to apply this selector to remove all images other than the first in a div that looks like this.

```
$(".item_cont a img").not(":eq(0)").hide();
```

as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jojoroxursox/9AFpv/

however when applied to a masonry grid it removes all items, even the ones that only have one image.

http://jsfiddle.net/jojoroxursox/M9Yau/

any suggestions?

Comment: I strongly _suggest_ you accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: completely agree. sloppy of me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you'd want to select all but the first item in the matched element list overall.  [`.slice(startIndex)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) is perfect for this set reduction, like so:

```
$(".item_cont a img").slice(1).hide();
```

[Here is your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/M9Yau/3/), though I personally get 403s for all images...so it can't be seen working clearly.

If I misunderstood and you want to remove all but the first *per* `.item_cont`, what you'll want is something more on the selector side, like [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (greater than index):

```
$(".item_cont a img:gt(0)").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var imgToKeep = $(".item_cont a img")[0];
$("img").each(function () {
    if (this !== imgToKeep) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldnt get any of these to work, enven though they definitely work in test environments. I wonder if its masonry thats creating the problem.

the workaround was to use regex in the backend to output the 2nd level of images in a hidden div.